# Kmeans / Codo de Jambú (Elbow Method) - Automatizar la interpretación gráfica del codo

Tags: data, math

como va? espero que bien.

Esta vez el post está dirigido a entender si existe alguna manera "matemática" para detectar cual es el Codo de Jambú en una gráfica, para que al ejecutar el algoritmo en lugar de una gráfica me devuelva además la cantidad óptima de clúster sin tener la necesidad de interpretarlos a ojo.

Para esto se me ocurrió la siguiente formula matemática, la cual no sé si servirá por lo que me gustaría que se ponga en cuestionamiento mi idea, si ya existe una forma de hacer esto estaré agradecido si la pueden compartir.

La idea se basa en que para punto del eje X de la gráfica (cuales indican la cantidad de clúster) se hagan cálculos sobre 3 puntos (A, B y C), siendo B el punto analizado, A el punto que está inmediatamente atrás y C el punto inmediatamente adelante, ya que lo que se busca es ver el punto donde se forma el codo para lo cual necesitamos al menos 3 puntos de referencia.

La idea es:

1. Calcular la diferencia de WCSS (eje Y) entre A y B (D1)
2. Calcular la diferencia de WCSS (eje Y) entre B y C (D2)
3. Dividir D1/D2

El cociente me da como resultado cuantas veces entra D2 en D1, y a este cociente lo llamo "puntaje de codo" y cada uno de los puntos del eje X van a tener un puntaje de codo, excluyendo al primero y al último ya que en el calculo para el primer nodo no existe un punto A, y en el último caso no existe un punto C; De los cuales el que sea más grande o cual tenga puntaje más alto (donde quepa más d2 dentro de d1) estaría indicando el Codo de Jambú óptimo.

Poniendo a prueba la teoría, desarrollé en SQL un código que corre los siguientes algoritmos:

- Codo de Jambú, devolviendo los datos para cargar la gráfica (en un Excel por ejemplo), aplicando los conceptos matemáticos que traje a colación.
- Kmeans++ para determinar la posición inicial de los centroides.
- Kmeans para la agrupación no supervisada de la población bajo estudio.

Acá los resultados de SQL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá la gráfica del Codo de Jambú
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá la gráfica del agrupamiento resultante del estudio realizado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras ejecutar varias veces el mismo script dependiendo el centroide inicial (el cual tiene el valor de una muestra seleccionada de forma aleatoria) los resultados suelen variar, a veces afecta a la repartición de las muestras a las distintas agrupaciones, y algunos pocos casos afecta inclusive a la cantidad de agrupaciones formadas, por lo que estoy acá compartiendo mis dudas con ustedes.

Los valores de las muestras son extraídos de una base de datos con el objeto de estudiar la técnica. Pueden acceder a los mismos a través del siguiente link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Td6YnHhnJT7Dg2D-2aedyB-wBkK3JdFyoxFDGir43Fc/edit?usp=sharing

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el data set.
El algoritmo que implemento en mi código SQL funciona bien cuando los grupos tienden a estar más separados que juntos.
Claramente el codo de jambú no funciona de forma óptima con el conjunto de data set que traje a colación.
Dejo abierto el foro por si le sirve a alguien en algún momento.